# Losing selection highlight in NSOutlineView subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsoutlineview

To customize the default blue gradient highlight style I made a **subclass** of `NSOutlineView` and overrode the method `-highlightSelectionInClipRect`, like so:

```
- (void)highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)theClipRect
{
    NSRange aVisibleRowIndexes = [self rowsInRect:theClipRect];
    NSIndexSet *aSelectedRowIndexes = [self selectedRowIndexes];
    NSInteger aRow = aVisibleRowIndexes.location;
    NSInteger anEndRow = aRow + aVisibleRowIndexes.length;

    for (int aRow; aRow < anEndRow; aRow++) {
        if([aSelectedRowIndexes containsIndex:aRow]) {
            // draw gradient
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but sometimes the background is not drawn. On the screenshot below you can see how the selection highlight is not drawn when clicking on the first item after the last one was selected.

[image: Loosing selection highlight on step 4]

It seems as if this only happens if **the new selected item is not directly beneath or above the old selected** one. Selecting five items in the order 1-2-3-4-5-4-3-2-1 always draws the appropriate background, anything else (e.g. 1-2-5) not.

Why is this happening? If you need any more details I will be glad to add some more code, but at the meantime I have no clue where to search for this behaviour.

Comment: For starters, I'd look at the declaration of aRow in the for loop, assuming this is an actual code snippet.   If this is, the aRow you calculate will be replaced by the uninitialized aRow in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my (very simple) solution using blocks:

```
- (void)highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
{
    [[self selectedRowIndexes] enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
     {
         // draw gradient
    }];
}
```